# can't redim an array in vbs

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying to redim and preserve an array so it will rmeove any blank lines from the array. But I get an error

> type mismatch

on the line where the redim is. Do I need to set teh lbound and ubound of the array first?

```
option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1
Const ForAppending = 8
Const ForWriting = 2

Dim objFSO, objUsersFile, arrFileLines, a, strDN, objUser, arrMemberOf, regex, group, strData, strObject, objRootDSE, objConnection, ADLogFile
Dim objCommand, WshShell, TriStateTrue, strDNSDomain, objRecordSet, workdir, strUsers, strDateAndTime, strDayOfMonth, strMonth, strYear, strDate, strTime
Dim strOU, strFlag, Args, strfile, objFile, strAddRemoveUser, strAdminsGroup, strUserDN, ADSuccessLogFile, strUser, strGroup, objGroup
Dim strType, strPreventMDriveDelete, strAddRemove, wshNetwork, strDomainName, strPreventWin7Upgrade, strWin7Advert
Dim ADFailedLogFile, strMachine, objComputer, strMachineDN, objMachine, strPackageCode, strAppInstall, strNTName, k
Dim arrFileLine()

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Args = WScript.Arguments

strType = "User"

strAddRemove = "Add"

strOU = "EU"

strAdminsGroup = strOU & "-SYS-MGRT-DESKTOP"

'set date for use in file names
strDayOfMonth = Right("0" & Day(Date()),2)
strMonth = Right("0" & Month(Date()),2)
strYear = Right (Year(Date()),4)
strDate = strDayOfMonth & "-" & strMonth & "-" & strYear
strTime = replace(Time(),":",".")
strDateAndTime = strDate & "-" & strTime

Workdir = "C:\script\admin"
Set ADSuccessLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(workdir & "\Logs\Success" & strDateAndTime & ".txt", ForAppending,True)
Set ADFailedLogFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(workdir & "\Logs\Failed" & strDateAndTime & ".txt", ForAppending,True)

strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.get("defaultNamingContext") 

strFile = Args.item(0)
If right (strFile,3) = "txt" Then
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, 1)
    k = 0
        Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
            strUser = Trim(objFile.ReadLine)
                If (strUser <> "") Then
                    ReDim Preserve arrFileLines(k)
                    arrFileLines(k) = strUser
                    k = k + 1
                End If
        Loop
    objFile.Close
Else
    ReDim arrFileLines(0)
    arrFileLines(0) = strFile
End If
for each struser in arrfilelines
    wscript.echo struser
next
```

Answer (score 0):

1. arrFileLine <> arrFileLines
2. `Dim aX()` creates a fixed array of no size; VBScript can't even *Bound() it

So use `Dim arrFileLines` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

found the issue when diming the array i needed arrFileLines() not arrFileLines

Comment: You did it again and still have the spurious ().